# Deleting a session after http_basic_authenticate_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning ruby on rails, well

I have white this code to do a login and autenticate to edit post, but I dont find how to do a logout, I only can login, and then I can't do logout, please help  me

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

http_basic_authenticate_with :name => 'admin', :password => 'meteoro', :except => [:index, :show]
# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
def index
@posts = Post.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @posts }
end
end
```

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, so it's really a convention of the browser (client) and server that make you "logged in" for a given request.  [Check out the answer in this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/755/how-does-basic-http-auth-work) -- the important part is that once authentication is complete, the server will respond with an `Authorization` header which the browser will pass back.  Manually clearing the header in the controller by doing something like `request.headers['Authorization'] = ''` should work,  I think.

Comment: not true! the server can't force that comportement via the response.headers

Comment: I have corrected my answer to indicate that a request, not a response is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the client to loose the `Authorization` header, by forcing it to place a request with another one

Here is how I did it, in a /logout view, using a jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url : '/empty_200_page', 
  method : 'GET', 
  beforeSend : function(req) { 
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'nope'); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: This is a question about how one would accomplish a log out using ROR.  While certainly Possible via an Ajax request, this would not be a typical solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to logout, you can add a new action with blank username and password. For example:

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show, :logout]
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "", password: "", only: :logout

  def logout
    redirect_to articles_path
  end
```

also add a route for logout

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
....
  get :logout, to: "articles#logout"
end
```

and add a link for logout in any view file

```
<%= link_to "LOGOUT", :logout %>
```

when user clicks the LOGOUT link, it requests for login. An empty OK will logout the user.

Answer (score -1):

By default the credentials which are entered by you are stored in the static headers and there is effectively no way to Logout from the system...

Read this wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages

Comment: you're answer is partially right, there is no way 'from the server side' - but there is a way by forcing the client to overwrite that Authorization header - see my answer